# How to compare the number of occurrences in strings in 2 different lists?

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I have a dictionary containing 2 lists A and B. Please refer to the example.

Lists A and B contain multiple strings where each string contains numbers which are comma-delimited.

My question is, how do I compare the number of occurrences of each string in list A with the string with the same index in string B and then print only the ones that are equal?
e.g. The last string of A contains only 2 elements whereas the one in B contains 3, thus making it not equal whereas the other strings are all equal to each other in terms of the number of elements in each string.

```
data = {
    'A' : ["2,3,4,5,6,10", "3,4,5,6,7", "2,3,4", "4,5,6,7,8,9,1", "1,2"],
    'B' : ["2,2,2,2,2,3", "2,2,2,2,2", "1,2,1", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1", "3,4,5"]
}
```

what I currently have come up with:

```
new_list_1 = []
new_list_2 = []

a = data['A']
b = [[int(x) for x in i.split(',')] for i in a]


e = data['B']
f = [[int(x) for x in i.split(',')] for i in e]
# print(f)


for x,y in zip(b, f):
    if len(x) == len(y):
        new_list_1.append(b)
        new_list_2.append(f)

print(new_list_2)
```

However, this gives the following as output:

```
[[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 4, 5]], [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 4, 5]], [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 4, 5]], [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 4, 5]]]
```

Comment: so, in your example what output you expect? 4, since it's the number of elements with equal length in both lists?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, I expect the output to only print out those strings where both have same number of elements and ignore the ones that do not

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you **also** demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right. If you would like a nudge getting started, take a look at `zip()` applied to the values of your dictionary. A list comprehension makes this a one liner.

Comment: @JonSG, Hi Jon, thank you. I have put the method that i was working with; could you please have a look into it and tell me where i may be going wrong?

Comment: Could you provide your required output? There seems to be several misunderstandings here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
data = {
    'A' : ["2,3,4,5,6,10", "3,4,5,6,7", "2,3,4", "4,5,6,7,8,9,1", "1,2"],
    'B' : ["2,2,2,2,2,3", "2,2,2,2,2", "1,2,1", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1", "3,4,5"]
}
newlist = []
for x, y in zip(data['A'], data['B']):
    if len(x.split(',')) == len(y.split(',')):
        newlist.append([x, y])
print(newlist)
```

**Output:**

```
[['2,3,4,5,6,10', '2,2,2,2,2,3'], ['3,4,5,6,7', '2,2,2,2,2'], ['2,3,4', '1,2,1'], ['4,5,6,7,8,9,1', '1,1,1,1,1,1,1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your data as:

```py
data = {
    'A' : ["2,3,4,5,6,10", "3,4,5,6,7", "2,3,4", "4,5,6,7,8,9,1", "1,2"],
    'B' : ["2,2,2,2,2,3", "2,2,2,2,2", "1,2,1", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1", "3,4,5"]
}
```

You can get back a list of tuples where the lengths of the values cast from strings to lists match via `zip()` and a list comprehension like:

```py
results = [
    (a, b) for (a, b) in zip(*data.values())
    if len(a.split(",")) == len(b.split(","))
]
print(results)
```

This will give you:

```
[
    ('2,3,4,5,6,10', '2,2,2,2,2,3'),
    ('3,4,5,6,7', '2,2,2,2,2'),
    ('2,3,4', '1,2,1'),
    ('4,5,6,7,8,9,1', '1,1,1,1,1,1,1')
]
```

A slightly simpler version that does not use `values()` that produces the same result would be:

```py
results = [
    (a, b) for (a, b) in zip(data["A"], data["B"])
    if len(a.split(",")) == len(b.split(","))
]
print(results)
```

Comment: I've re-read the OP's question. I don't think it's got anything to do with string lengths. It seems to be concerned with the number of numbers in each string (taken as comma-delimited values)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thanks, I updated this to reflect your interpretation that seems correct to me as well.